# Why intensity of sound increase when we blow harder in one end open tube?

Tags: waves, frequency

In my textbook a question given like what will increase 'pitch' or 'intensity' of sound when blow harder in test tube.

What's wrong in thinking this way
"Blowing harder will increase velocity of particle near open end, and this will decrease pressure at that end (Bernoulli pressure equation if fluids)

And thus create a nod (partially or completely) at that end instead of antinode in non blowing case. Clearly it increase frequency of wave inside it.

And amplitude and speed if wave remain same due to tube and air as medium respectively.

So *according to it pitch should increase and intensity should be constant* but answer was Vice versa.

**what I am missing ?**